# Connect the Dots Problem

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, combinatorics, solvability

[image: dots puzzle]

Using the image above, the rules are every dot must have a line through it, no diagonal lines, no crossing over lines, no backtracking, no going out of bounds, and no picking up the pencil to start at another location. A friend says it is solvable and I want to say it isn't. Is this puzzle solvable under these set of rules? If yes, post your solution.

Comment: Color the dots like squares of a chessboard, then this puzzle has been posted here tens of times.

Comment: It really depends on how out of bounds is defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **No, it isn't solvable.**

The proof is as follows.

> Colour the dots black and white in a checkerboard pattern. Then you have 8 dots of one colour and 10 of the other, say 8 white and 10 black (the upper right and bottom left dots being black). But at each step you must pass either from a black dot to a white dot or vice verse, so any valid path must pass through the same number of dots of both colours, give or take one. So there's no valid path passing through 8 and 10 dots of the two respective colours.

Answer (score 6):

By the spirit of the rules, @Rand al'Thor is quite correct. However... your friend insists it is possible.

My guess as to the workaround is

> Nothing says that a line segment must start or end on a dot.

This leads to an answer such as the following:

> [image: Forgive the Freehand lines]

Comment: I just finished something similar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8JUK.png - I think "no diagonals" is *meant* to cover these :p

Comment: Is that going out of bounds?